mysql-server on debian 12 has no installation candidate?
I have a fresh Debian 12, and I want MySQL 8, not MariaDB. The internet says that's not a problem, but I can't install mysql-server.
What I did:
sudo apt install gnupg
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.33-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.33-1_all.deb
sudo apt update

That part all worked fine. I see the mysql repo being updated:
Get:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bookworm InRelease [22.7 kB]
Get:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bookworm/mysql-8.0 Sources [949 B]
Get:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bookworm/mysql-apt-config i386 Packages [566 B]

And the package is known:
$ sudo apt policy mysql-server
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

but I can't install it:
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

I saw somewhere (I don't remember where, I've been reading the entire internet for this) that Debian 12 bookwork doesn't support mysql, or the other way around, and that I have to install mariadb. I really need mysql, not mariadb.
According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/ I can still install mysql if I want. And according to https://www.linuxbuzz.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-12/ And many more. So mysql-server should work on Debian 12..?
Install mysql 8.0 on Debian 12 seems relevant, but that's a different error.

I remember where I saw that debian 12 bookworm is not supported. Not on the internet, but in the mysql installer if I did a sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.33-1_all.deb instead of using dpkg. It let me select a different distro (like Debian 11 bullseye), but mysql-server still wouldn't install.

I'm installing on a mini PC that was Windows 10, with an Intel i7-5557U processor. Apparently it's shit, but I can't imagine that's the reason for this.

If I try to install mysql-community-server:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-community-server

and if I tab-complete with mysql- prefix:
rudie@devver4:~/tmp$ sudo apt install mysql-[TAB][TAB]
mysql-apt-config  mysql-common      mysql-sandbox

Looks like there's no mysql-server package at all, but apt policy mysql-server still works (see above).

If I do a sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config, I can re-select what to want to install. Selected:
MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-8.0)
MySQL Connectors (Currently selected: Disabled)

I think that's correct. APT sources config (/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list) seems to be correct too:
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-apt-config
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-8.0
#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-tools
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bookworm mysql-8.0


What apt update finds (I think):
$ ls /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.*
repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_bookworm_InRelease
repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_bookworm_mysql-8.0_source_Sources
repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_bookworm_mysql-apt-config_binary-i386_Packages

Only 1 *_Packages file, and that contains only Package: mysql-apt-config.
In repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_bookworm_mysql-8.0_source_Sources there is a Package: mysql-community with Package-List that includes mysql-community-server etc, but I can't install mysql-community either:
E: Unable to locate package mysql-community

Why is there no Package: mysql-server or Package: mysql-community-server in those files??

@ChrisDavies That doesn't work: dpkg-query: error: --listfiles needs a valid package name but ..... is not. I tried all kinds of paths. Doesn't work with .deb file, only package name?

@ChrisDavies Zero packages found for 'mysql-server*', and also zero for '*mysql*server*'.

The apt policy output indicates that the package is known, but only indirectly (through a dependency of some kind); if it were really known, as in apt finding the package itself in the repository, it would have an installation candidate version.

@StephenKitt So the mysql repo doesn't expose any packages? The 3 I can see are very few.

Based on your apt update output snippet, you’re running i386. The Oracle MySQL packages are no longer published on that architecture. If your hardware supports it (it should, the CPU is a 64-bit CPU), you should install Debian using the amd64 (64-bit x86) architecture.

I did install Debian amd64. This is the ISO file I downloaded on Windows: debian-11.11.0-amd64-netinst.iso. -- edit -- No, that's the Debian 11 I was about to try. This is the Debian 12 ISO: debian-12.8.0-i386-netinst.iso OMG OMG OMG Finally someone who reads! You!

That was it. That's all. I'm an idiot, proof once again. There should be a big warning on installing the mysql repo: "You're on i386 architecture dummy!" Thank you thank you so much ❤️, I've been going mad the last few days.

The package name you'll need to install from that repository is mysql-community-server, not mysql-server.
Apparently Oracle has renamed the packages to make it really clear which one is the free community-supported version and which is the licensed enterprise version.
See for yourself the package list of the repository: https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/bookworm/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages
Package: mysql-server
Source: mysql-community
Version: 8.0.40-1debian12
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Installed-Size: 67
Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.40-1debian12)
Homepage: http://www.mysql.com/
Priority: optional
Section: database
Filename: pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-server_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb
Size: 58356
SHA256: cb673f44842405880b283906732b9c4e5f4096e3c6060c665587fe15a8bd43b9
SHA1: e00aa77fda8404f4387311e5544028118a436631
MD5sum: dfad93281ecb72799a3d355b091425b5
Description: MySQL Server meta package depending on latest version
 The MySQL(TM) software delivers a very fast, multi-threaded, multi-user,
 and robust SQL (Structured Query Language) database server. MySQL Server
 is intended for mission-critical, heavy-load production systems as well
 as for embedding into mass-deployed software. MySQL is a trademark of
 Oracle. This is a meta package that depends on the latest mysql server
 package available in the repository.

mysql-server is now just a metapackage that is supposed to depend on the latest mysql-community-server package, which is also a metapackage that just depends on the appropriate mysql-community-server-core, mysql-common and mysql-client packages. Likewise mysql-client depends on mysql-community-client which depends on mysql-community-client-core. And you can see they exist in the appropriate path in the repository's package pool directory: https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/
...
[FILE] mysql-client_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb                    11-Oct-2024 15:29    57k
...  
[FILE] mysql-common_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb                    11-Oct-2024 15:29    58k 
...
[FILE] mysql-community-client-core_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb     11-Oct-2024 15:29   1.8M  
...
[FILE] mysql-community-client_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb          11-Oct-2024 15:29   3.0M  
...
[FILE] mysql-community-server-core_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb     11-Oct-2024 15:29  29.6M  
...
[FILE] mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb  11-Oct-2024 15:29   1.2M  
...
[FILE] mysql-server_8.0.40-1debian12_amd64.deb                    11-Oct-2024 15:29    57k 

Note that the datestamps indicate the packages of the 8.0.40 version were created just last week: there might be some last-minute glitches or mirror update issues.
Also note that the mysql-apt-config will pop up a question dialog when you install it with dpkg: perhaps installing with apt install <URL> caused that dialog to be bypassed with default choices assumed, and you got incomplete repository definitions as a result? Try dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config.

That doesn't exist either. The only mysql-* packages are mysql-apt-config, mysql-common, mysql-sandbox

The package exist, see apt policy in OP, but there's no installation candidate.

Good analysis. I'm convinced. But apt still can't find it. See last OP edit about dpkg-reconfigure. I think the repo config is correct, and apt update seems to work. apt install <URL> was only one of the options I tried, they all had the same result: no mysql-server or mysql-community-server package. I've reinstalled Debian 12 about 5 times now :D Can I debug the apt source better? See why their repo has the package, but my apt can't see it?

I see you found out the reason. Most enterprise distributions have gone 64-bit only so long ago, I did not even consider that Debian might still have the i386 version available. But of course they have.

Right!? I was convinced obviously I installed amd64, what else would I install? I'm kinda surprised everything else worked fine. Only mysql-server was not supported. Anyway, thanks for all the info
